# get group and role details from AAD in a native application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Will I be able to get the group, role details of a user from a native application using Graph API. As it's a native application, I do not have a Client Secret. Please let me know.
I referred

1. http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/authorization-cloud-applications-using-ad-groups/
2. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims

Comment: It's not clear at all what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with getting such information using Graph API. But you don't have to use Graph API at all. With proper setup you can get group and role claims with a normal authentication through Azure Active Directory.